# "Too localized" on SO is generally the same as "Off-topic" that belongs to CodeReview.SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, off-topic, too-localized

The *too localized* close vote description states:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question
>   more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

In SO's case a too localized question in my experience is generally a "fix my code for me" question where you'd basically have to go to hunt for typos, misspellings, incorrect variables or just mistakes in the code that don't present a general issue that could possibly benefit others, not to mention that it wouldn't really be searchable by any meaningful keywords. So, those are largely code review questions.

Perhaps, and I assume that this could only happen after CodeReview.SE is out of beta, the *too localized* close vote could, optionally, do the same as an off-topic vote with migration to CodeReview.SE?

Comment: I don't think typo questions are useful for Code Review either.

Comment: So, questions that are asked in languages other than English should go to code review?

Comment: Yeah, typos were a more extreme example that really wouldn't belong anywhere

Comment: You might want to read the Code Review FAQ. You don't seem to understand its purpose.

Comment: Ok, case closed, code review is not always or often the best fit for SO's too localized questions, I was wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code Review is for reviewing *working* code, most questions on SO are about code that doesn't work yet. A very large number of "too localized" questions on SO would be off-topic code review.

In general I also don't think that misusing a regular close reason as a migration tool would be a good idea. Migration should be a deliberate action, not a side-effect.

Comment: Hence the suggestion of *optionally* casting an off-topic > code review vote

Comment: @pilsetnieks There are the regular migration paths for that purpose, and Code Review will be eligible to appear there if it is out of beta and there is sufficient demand.